# Master list filtered from other lists based on matching values

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine the following:

you have a Person which can be assigned to one or more countries.
the same person could be assigned to one or more sites
the same person could be assigned to one or more regions

The user can select which countries, sites and regions to filter on and should only show those users that fulfill that criteria.

I am using in memory collections from the data source I have and want to figure out the best way of being able to filter the people (person) who meet all the criterias i.e:

the user can choose sites, regions and countries and for all of these combined, i want to bring back the list of persons that match this criteria.

Any ideas how?

The structure of the Person object is as follows:

```
ID
Name
Countries (List)
Regions (List)
Sites (List)
```

I cannot seem to figure out the correct LINQ syntax to filter the master list to get me just those Persons that meet the selected criteria.

any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show filter object? How are you passing filter data to your method?

Comment: Is there some sort of database associated with this project? and do you have an existing schema?  If so, which framework are you using to interact with that database, and what is the schema

Comment: also, is there any relationship between Countries, Regions, and Sites?

Comment: So, the filter object is basically a collection of ID's sent from the UI in its own lists (1 for countries, 1 for regions, 1 for sites). There is a DB associated with it however this is external and the project uses an API to do the external calling and there is no way I can supply a filter to it - I have to do the filtering. There is NO relationship between these objects except each user has countries and or regions and or sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var countryIdsToCheck = new List<int> { 1,3,5 };
var regionIdsToCheck = new List<int> { 6,8 };
var siteIdsToCheck= new List<int> { 35 };

var result = yourDbContext.Persons;
if(countryIdsToCheck.Any())
{
  result= result.Where(s=>s.Countries.Any(x=>countryIdsToCheck.Contains(x.Id));
}
if(regionIdsToCheck.Any())
{
  result= result.Where(s=>s.Regions.Any(y=>regionIdsToCheck .Contains(y.Id));
}
if(siteIdsToCheck.Any())
{
  result= result.Where(s=>s.Sites.Any(z=>siteIdsToCheck.Contains(z.Id));
}
var finalResult=result.ToList();
```

Or a single liner

```
var result = yourDbContext.Persons
              .Where(s=>s.Countries.Any(x=>countryIdsToCheck.Contains(x.Id))
                  || s.Regions.Any(y=>regionIdsToCheck.Contains(y.Id))
                  || s.Sites.Any(z=>siteIdsToCheck.Contains(z.Id))).ToList();
```

`ToList()` call is not necessary. I added it so that it will help you to debug it with quick watch and breakpoints ( `ToList()` execute the expression and copy the result a a new list(eager loading))

Comment: Thanks. I believe this works (now having data integrity issues). FYI I don't have access to dbContext but either way that does not matter. Thanks again.

Comment: then replace `yourDbContext.Persons` with the collection of Person's coming from your database table(s)

Answer (score 1):

If the user selection is saved in let's say:

```
var chosenCountries = new List<Country>();
var chosenRegions  = new List<Region>();
var chosenSite = new List<Site>();
```

Then it'd simply be filtering on those

```
var result = persons;
if(chosenCountries.Any())
{
result = result.Where(p=>p.Countries.Any(c=>chosenCountries.Any(cc=>cc.Id == c.Id));
}
if(chosenRegions.Any())
{
result = result.Where(p=>p.Regions.Any(r=>chosenRegions.Any(cr=>cr.Id == r.Id));
}
return result.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show other alternative in case the filter object looks like:

```
public class Filter
{
    public int CountryID;
    public int RegionID;
    public int SiteID;
}

var filter = new List<Filter>();

var result = persons.Where(p => 
       filter.Any(f => p.Countries.Any(c => c.ID == f.CountryID) &&
                  f => p.Regions.Any(r => r.ID == f.RegionID) &&
                  f => p.Sites.Any(s => s.ID == f.SiteID)));
```